# flinkCEP query to database within select() function or SimpleCondition/IterativeCondition

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, apache-flink, flink-cep

[Using a JDB connector I make queries to a PostgreSQL database and process the results. This works fine!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm4s3.png)

[BUT, when I try to query within a **PatternFlatSelectFunction**, in order the query results to be the condition on which I collect the new events, I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6wVd.png)

Can anyone help me? I would like to get a good understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Could you please not link images, but copy the code examples to the question itself. This way they won't get outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The `PatternFlatSelectFunction` has to be `Serializable` as it is sent over to all TaskManagers.

If I understood you correctly you are trying to execute `DataSet` program from within the `SelectFunction`. That is a completely wrong approach and this is not possible, as that would mean you are spawning new jobs from within TaskManagers.

You may use other libraries to query your DB from within `PatternSelectFunction`. Also make sure it is `Serializable`.